# See total download speed on server CentOS

Tags: linux, centos

I have a few PHP scripts running every 10 minutes on my server downloading backup files, Is there a way to see the total MB/s download speed the server is currently pulling ?

The server is running CentOS.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To see the current download speed you could use `iftop` (`yum install iftop`).

Comment: Did this answer your question?